# BerkeleyDB maximize performance and minimize data loss

Tags: c++, berkeley-db, data-loss

How to prevent damage to the BerkeleyDB database if during the write operation failed on power loss?

Loss of the current data is not terrible. The main thing that is already stored data has not been corrupted and has quick access to them when you resume operation.

Thus, the maximum possible recording speed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need durability (the D in ACID) which is provided
by databases created with DB_INIT_TXN to recover from
interruptions like power loss.

Already stored (i.e. committed) data will be recreated
as part of db_recover operations. You will need to ensure
that transactional logs are preserved and available.